# Why is the speed of elquent is lower than db query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have two query in lumen like this

1. `Doc:all();`
2. `DB:table('docs')->get();`

Speed of first is 946 ms, speed of second is 46 ms (in Postman)

Can you tell me about this?

Comment: you mean `DB::table('docs')->get()`?

Comment: Yes . I edited my question.

Answer (score 6):

```
DB::table('docs')->get();
```

returns a collection of basic objects with no added logic.

```
Doc:all();
```

returns a collection of Doc models. Hydrating every Doc model in the results with all the added logic (`$appends`, `$casts`, `$with`, `$withCount`) takes more processing time.

Answer (score 0):

For these cases you'll always get better speed in query builder, but in long term for example while playing with table relations and other complex queries you have to write very less and simple code with eloquent. In case of query builder you have to deal with complex join and stuff.